# Create a File in src directory of Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, filepath

I want to create a file in the current directory of eclipse plugin.
I tried to create the file using :

> File file = new File("filename.txt");

But, it is not working.

EDIT: I want to create the file in the same directory as that of "src" folder

Comment: I'm confused where do you want to create the file exactly? With the command your using, you will simply create a variable referring to a file not the actual file and it will be created in the directory of the project your currently working in.

Comment: Do you want to create a file in an Eclipse workspace? This requires using a Eclipse API.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create empty file within the pproject dir tree? or you want to create new file programatically? If you want to create empy file, go to File>New>Empty file (or similar, I do not have eclipse installed, Im writing out of memory), and if programatically: you have written line that initializes file at given path (if file cannot be initialized (no such file, or similar) - this will throw an exeption), but does not create it. To create file you need to write second instruction, just like:

```
file.create();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the location (inside your project) is correct, then simply do this (not including try catch etc):

```
File test = new File("test.txt");
test.createNewFile();
```